# Regex matching using SED in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I want to match the following line with the regex in sed:

```
db=connect_str=DBI:SQLAnywhere:ENG=ABC1_hostname12;DBN=ABC12;UID=USERID;PWD=passwd123;LINKS=tcpip{host=10.11.12.13:1234}
```

The regex I am using is:

```
sed -n '/ABC1_.+;/p' Config/db_conn.cfg
```

but this does not work. On the other hand, it works if I use:

```
sed -n '/ABC1_.*;/p' Config/db_conn.cfg
```

Can someone please explain why it's not working? Also is there another way to match it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because sed is basic regex by default, which needs `+` to be escaped or else it represents a literal `+` instead of a regex `+`:

```
sed -n '/ABC1_.\+;/p' Config/db_conn.cfg
```

To use regex you're familiar with try `sed -r -n` (extended regex) and then you can do:

```
sed -r -n '/ABC1_.+;/p' Config/db_conn.cfg
```

Comment: If that's all you need to do, `egrep 'ABC1_.+;'  Config/db_conn.cfg` does the same thing more simply and probably faster.